# How to create a yarn "pom pom"?

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image: Sample of image to create]

I'm trying to create a yarn *pom pom* as shown the the sample image. But all the tutorials I can find online teaches how to create fur texture. Is there a simple way to create this?

Comment: I had an "o sh." moment at first when reading the title, the m letter really looks like r and n sticked together ><

Comment: 

Comment: @Gorgious Keming strikes again...  I actually read the title as "yam pom pom", but I think I like yours better.

Comment: Fixed the kerning.

Comment: @jiwopene (Boooooooooo) - haha, it was also a fun quick lesson on what "kerning" is.

Comment: @Gorgious you're not the only one, btw, "rn" and "m" are so-called [confusables](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp?a=m&r=None)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a try:

[image]

You could create a ball, and a piece of wool that will be the hair of the ball. Also give some hair to the piece of wool:

[image]

Here is how the material looks like, give it a bit a *Subsurface Scattering*, put the *Sheen* at 1, give it a bit of *Emission*, mix with a *Transparent* node with a *Layer Weight* as factor, give it a bit of *Bump*:

[image]

Comment: Nice one but why give it emission? Is it to fake the natural SSS/real or light bounces?

Comment: +1 for matching the lighting conditions as well, this is a nice approach, but some more details on how to add the hair via particles might be useful.

Comment: @Bruno yes it's a way to make the material a bit lighter, at least in eevee, SSS gives something a bit "buttery", but maybe there's another way?

Comment: @Freddie R, which hair do you mean? Maybe the original poster will ask for details...

Comment: Wow this looks really nice. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

1. Add an icosphere or a quad sphere
2. Add a particle system to it, set to *Hair*
3. Under amount set a lower value (about 200 for a default cube of 2 x 2)
4. Under *Physics* set *Brownian* to a low value like about 0.3
5. Set *Children* type to *Simple* and reduce the *Display* and *Render Amount* to a value of about 100.
6. Under *Clump* set to about 0.3
7. Set *Kink* to *Braid* with a low amplitude like 0.7
8. Increase the frequency to a high value like 20
9. Under the hair *Render > Path* settings increase *Steps* to a higher value of about 8, to make braids visible.

[image]

Comment: This looks like those evil attack robots from the Matrix. lol.... thanks for the help I'll look at the settings and play around with it.

Comment: The squiddies? Hehe